# How to annotate the type of a variable that holds class objects

Tags: python, annotations, metaprogramming

I am using a variable to hold a factory for different classes.
The code runs but the PyCharm IDE wants me to annotate the type of the factory var since I am calling it.

Q1: How should I annotate the 'factory' variable, what is the type to insert for XXX?
Q2: Is this a pythonic way to encode a factory?

```
Foo(object):
    pass

Bar:
    pass


factory: XXX = Foo if something else Bar

instance = factory()
```

Comment: Usually factory pattern doesn't used on constructors (it's not logical)

Comment: maybe factory: Foo = Foo?

Comment: @olvin my understanding of a factory is that is separates choice of implementing class as the code above does.  I think you CAN use class constructors to implement a factory, as I have done. Perhaps what I did it not pythonic, please correct it.

Comment: @ron your approach requires there to be a common super class, but also I think is it not correct, you declared factory to be an INSTANCE of Foo.  not an instance of Type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it the most "pythonic" way, but definitely most obvious:

```
class A:
    var = 1


class B:
    var = 0


class C:
    var = -1


class PseudoFactory:
    @staticmethod
    def get_constructor(some_argument):
        if some_argument < 0:
            return A
        elif some_argument == 0:
            return B
        else:
            return C
```

Test:

```
import random
for _ in range(10):
    rand = random.randrange(-1, 2)
    cls = PseudoFactory.get_constructor(rand)()
    print(f"Value: {rand}\tClass: {type(cls)}\tVar: {cls.var}")
```

It's not necessary to create class for such as "factory" in this simple example, but if you'll need to do something more advanced it could be useful. Anyway you can replace static method of class with just function.

Comment: Thaks, @Olvin but a factory should be an extensible interface (like a class).  so new modules and add new factory implementations.  Here we would have to edit the source code of this one function each time.  My main aim is to know how to correctly annotate the type for this variable.  Using duck typing a factory is any thing that is callable and does not return None...  but I don't know how to declare that (what to insert for XXX) in my code.  Thanks